# Swift 5 - navigationItem.title not showing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

My navigationItem.title behaves in a strange way.

When the viewController is pushed on to stack the title is not showing (top image). However, while viewController gets popped, the title becomes visible for a nanosecond or so (see bottom image).

[image]

[image]

This is how I set the title and add the barButtons. All in viewDidLoad.

```
navigationItem.title = "Mitt konto"
  
let backBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
let backBtnImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
backBtn.setBackgroundImage(backBtnImage, for: .normal)
backBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
backBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

let backBtnView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
backBtnView.bounds = view.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -10)
backBtnView.addSubview(backBtn)
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtnView)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    
let signOutImage = UIImage(named: "signout_item")?.withTintColor(.white)
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20, height: 20))
button.setBackgroundImage(signOutImage, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signoutButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

**UPDATE**
My view hierarchy is
NavigationController -> AnotherViewController -> ThisViewController

Where's my misstake? What is hiding the title?

Comment: Can you post an example project to GitHub?

Comment: first try to debug in console and check your title value.

Comment: @Kudos, where would be the best place to check for the title value?

Comment: when your are setting rightnavigationitem. Make here a breakpoint and check.

Comment: The value of navigationItem.title is "Mitt konto" when it's set, right before rightBarButtonItem is set and also in viewdidAppear. Thanks for trying to help, but the value is there. Note also in my question that the title appears during pop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that my backBtnView - despite setting its frame with width = 30 - was covering the title.

I found this out by giving the view a black background color. The view turned out to be way wider than 30.

Doing

```
backBtnView.frame.size.width = 30
```

after initialization fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in what hierarchy your view controller's are but you can set title as shown below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad()
 /* If view controller is a direct child of UINavigationController */
 self.title = "Title Here" 
/* If view controller's parent is a direct child of UINavigationController e.g. a child of embedded tab view controller */
 self.parent?.title = "Title Here" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but none of your suggestions work. As I state in the question, the title gets set. The problem seems to be it's hidden for some reason. However, I will update my question with my view hierarchy. Good point.

Comment: Your hierarchy is clear, but i need more information to debug this issue

Comment: Can you Please add whole view controller code